# Why do I get a 404 when calling Portainer via traefik

Tags: docker-compose, traefik, portainer

I have the problem that I get a 404 when I want to call my portainer-container via traefik

These are my labels for portainer:

```
- "traefik.enable=true"
- "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`portainer.domain.de`)"
- "traefik.port=9000"
- "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
- "traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=websecure"
- "traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
```

Traefik works just fine because other containers with similar config working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This is the same question as this thread [Traefik v2.5 not redirecting to portainer container. 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69905945/traefik-v2-5-not-redirecting-to-portainer-container-404-not-found/69949033#69949033)

Answer is Portainer doesnt support subpaths yet but it can be a feature request for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Although late, I hope this might be helpful to others: I found that the documentation around Portainer+Traefik v2 is inconsistent at best. Even the official Portainer Documentation is not presenting a valid solution.

If you are at the beginning and are trying for the first time to make them works, this is what got me through:

```
traefik.enable=true
traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`yourown.url.extension`)
traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=websecure
traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls.certresolver=myresolver
traefik.http.routers.portainer.service=portainer
traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000
traefik.http.routers.portainer-edge.rule=Host(`yourownedge.url.extension`)
traefik.http.routers.portainer-edge.entrypoints=websecure
traefik.http.routers.portainer-edge.tls.certresolver=myresolver
traefik.http.routers.portainer-edge.service=portainer-edge
traefik.http.services.portainer-edge.loadbalancer.server.port=8000
```

Please note: in my configuration "*myresolver*" is the name of the certresolver service. You should change it appropriately.